# AttributeError for selfloop_edges()

Tags: networkx, attributeerror

When executing the following:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

with open("nutrients.csv") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    G = nx.Graph(reader) #initialize Graph
print(G.nodes()) #this part works fine
print(repr(G.edges))
G.selfloop_edges()#attribute of question
```

It's coming back with

> AttributeError:"Graph" object has no attribute 'selfloop_edge'

Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You getting an error because this method has been moved from the base graph class into the main namespace, see [Migration guide from 1.X to 2.0](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/release/migration_guide_from_1.x_to_2.0.html). So either you're looking at the docs of 1.X or using code from previous releases.

You need to call this method as:

```
nx.selfloop_edges(G, data=True)
```